# Tridion Custom Page location

Tags: sdl-tridion, custom-page

Did you any one explore where does Custom page information stored in SDL Tridion?

Comment: The Custom Pages are set and visible in the UI by administrators. How will you use the location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom pages are stored in CustomPages.xml from below path

%TRIDION_HOME%web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Preferences\

Comment: Just to add: in Tridion 9 custom pages are stored in the database.

Comment: Hi, anyone knows where is this stored in the Web 8.6 please? This path doesn't exist for Web 8.6:  %TRIDION_HOME%web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Preferences\

Comment: Can you please check in database?

Comment: it does get stored on DB form SDL 8.6. you can find the details [APP_DATA] table

Answer (score 2):

it does get stored on DB form SDL 8.6. you can find the details [APP_DATA] table CM Database.

you can use the following code to read the value using core service

```
var client = CMSession.GetInstance().CoreServiceClient;
            var appData = client.ReadApplicationData(null, APPDATA_CUSTOMPAGES_ID);
            if (appData != null)
            {
                var ada = new ApplicationDataAdapter(appData);
                var appDataXml = ada.GetAs<XmlElement>();
                return appDataXml.OuterXml;
            }
```